# iOS MKLocalSearch only returns 10 results

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm starting to use the MKLocalSearch API for MapKit.

It works, and returns data, however it always appears to only return 10 results, no matter what size the region is or what the search term is. There doesn't appear to be any other configuration options or parameters to change any options about this.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get more than 10 results at a time from a local search request?

Comment: After reading some posts in the Apple developer forums this appears to be an issue with MapKit in general. No word from Apple about why. Assuming this will be fixed in a future version of iOS (hopefully).

Comment: The 10-result limit still exists as of Xcode 8.1.

Comment: Any updates regarding this? Is this fixed?

Comment: I doubt this will be "fixed", it is probably a set limit like Google Maps has. Google Maps has a limit of 5 results which is worst, but still what can be done with 10 results

Comment: 25 on iOS 17. Keep watching.